# What is the quickest way to merge multiple MPEG-4 files to a single DVD?

Tags: macos, video, dvd, osx-leopard, mpeg4

**I am using Mac OS X 10.5**

I have 30 MPEG-4 files, and I wish to burn these to a DVD that can be played in a standard DVD player (i.e. on a TV) What is the best way to burn these all to a DVD so that they play one after another.

I have tried using iMovie - but this takes far too long what with it's "generating thumbnails" and all that malarky.

I am really looking for a simple suggestion, as I don't need anything special, jst one move one after another.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Roxio's [Toast Titanium](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html) is easily the most simple. (I'm a video artist and I have to do this often.) Just drag the videos in and burn. As for the price tag... well, I think it's worth its weight in gold. Try a demo?

(You can also name the DVD, set it to loop continuously, or give it a menu if you want.)